# Extract sequences from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Starting from an array of arbitrary values I would like to be able to extract all sequences of a given value.
So if I started with this

```
[1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

and searched for 1. I would like to get back

```
[[1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

I have seen an implementation in AS though not clear enough for me to translate over: [finding sequences in AS3 array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485615/finding-sequences-in-as3-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote one from scratch with code comments:

```
function makeSequence(input, val) {
    var output = [], current = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] === val) {
            // if we have a matching value, add it to
            // the current match
            current.push(val);
        } else if (current.length) {
            // no match on current value, write out
            // any previous match
            output.push(current);
            current = [];
        }
    }
    // when done, make sure to add the last match
    if (current.length) {
        output.push(current);
    }
    return(output);
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YvsET/

Comment: Thanks that's nice simple answer

Answer (score 0):

[AS3 is based on ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript), and therefore, almost compatible (aside from the identifiers) and easily transformed to JS. Try this transformed version of the code (more or less, just stripped out the identifiers).

```
var prev = '',
    q = 0,
    result = [],
    numbers = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    i;
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
    if (prev != numbers[i]) {
        if (q > 0) {
            result.push(q);
        }
        q = 1;
        prev = numbers[i];
    } else {
        ++q;
    }
}
if (q > 0) {
    result.push(q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prev = '',q = 0, numbers = [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0];
for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){   
 if(prev!=numbers[i]){      
   if(q>0) 
     result.push(q);
   q=1;    
   prev=numbers[i];
  }   
   else 
      q++; 
} 
if(q>0) 
   result.push(q);
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

just another implementation using [filter() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): 
see example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NNmwr/2

```
var data         = [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    sequence_one = [];
    result       = [];

data.filter(function(d, i) {
   var current = data[i],
       prev    = data[i-1] || 0;

   if (current) {
      sequence_one.push(1);
      if (i === data.length -1) {
          result.push(sequence_one);    
      }
   }
   else {       
      if (prev) {
        result.push(sequence_one);
        sequence_one = [];
      }
   }
})

console.log(result); // [ [1], [1,1,1,1] ]
```